# R: how to count repeated character observations for a variable in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
> head(Sp)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  fechacolecta aniocolecta especievalida           fecha     
  <chr>              <dbl> <chr>                   <date>    
1 1865-07-17          1865 Geranium carolinianum   1865-07-17
2 1865-07-17          1865 Paspalum distichum      1865-07-17
3 1890-07-27          1890 Sporobolus pyramidatus  1890-07-27
4 1893-05-02          1893 Schiedeella durangensis 1893-05-02
5 1893-05-07          1893 Mesadenus polyanthus    1893-05-07
6 1893-05-07          1893 Mesadenus polyanthus    1893-05-07
```

And what I'm loooking for is to know how many times for example "Geranium carolinianum" is present in the data frame, if there was a way that the result could also maintain tha dates in which Geranium carolinianum is present it would be nice, also, I don't know the valuables the especievalida column might take. The `unique()` function only returns which species are present, but not how many times, and it only returns that variable, doesn´t include the date.
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With base R you could use `table` to get the frequencies of the observations, e.g.:

```r
table(Sp$especievalida)
```

To match up the names of the table and the column in the data.frame, you could use `match`.
That would give you:

```r
Sp$N <- with(Sp, table(especievalida)[match(especievalida, names(table(especievalida)))])
```

With the `data.table` package you could do:

```r
library(data.table)
data.table(Sp)[, N:= .N, by="especievalida"][]
#>    ID fechacolecta aniocolecta           especievalida      fecha N
#> 1:  1   1865-07-17        1865   Geranium carolinianum 1865-07-17 1
#> 2:  2   1865-07-17        1865      Paspalum distichum 1865-07-17 1
#> 3:  3   1890-07-27        1890  Sporobolus pyramidatus 1890-07-27 1
#> 4:  4   1893-05-02        1893 Schiedeella durangensis 1893-05-02 1
#> 5:  5   1893-05-07        1893    Mesadenus polyanthus 1893-05-07 2
#> 6:  6   1893-05-07        1893    Mesadenus polyanthus 1893-05-07 2
```

You could also summarize by both `fecha` and `especievalida` with this approach.

With `dplyr` you could use `add_count`:

```r
library(dplyr)
add_count(df, especievalida)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

Sp %>%
  # filters for the species
  filter(especievalida == "Geranium carolinianum") %>%
  # creates a column for count
  mutate(count = n())
```

**Data**

```
Sp <- read.table(text = "
fechacolecta aniocolecta especievalida fecha
1865-07-17 1865 'Geranium carolinianum' 1865-07-17
1865-07-17 1865 'Paspalum distichum' 1865-07-17
1890-07-27 1890 'Sporobolus pyramidatus' 1890-07-27
1893-05-02 1893 'Schiedeella durangensis' 1893-05-02
1893-05-07 1893 'Mesadenus polyanthus' 1893-05-07
1893-05-07 1893 'Mesadenus polyanthus' 1893-05-07", 
header = T)
```